# Why is my activity only running once?

Tags: android, android-activity, switching

I made this application go from one activity to the next. and then come back, but after it comes back to my main activity the button to go to the next view again does not do anything?  I thought it was from startActivityForResult but I did it a different way and its still not working...

Here is some code: if button is pushed

```
if (search.isPressed() && searchPressed == false) {
            // show search list
            switch1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
            // startActivityForResult(switch1, 0);
            startActivity(switch1);
        }
```

in next activity:

```
private OnItemClickListener listListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        String text = (String) ((TextView) arg1).getText();
        String[] selected = text.split(" - ");
        selected[0] = selected[0].replace(' ', '_');
        Log.w("COMPANY", selected[0]);
        Log.w("PART", selected[1]);

        // Intent data = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,
        // MainActivity.class);
        // data.putExtra("key", selected);
        // setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        MainActivity.searchData = selected;

        finish();

        // startActivity(switch2);
    }

};
```

////\ when item is pushed it goes back to main screen

Comment: Post some code. And check your log cat to see if there is any sort of error being thrown. If there is post the stack trace from that too.

Comment: Sorry i accidentally posted it before I was done the code is up now. Ill post logcat in a second.

Comment: You need to log search.isPressed() and searchPressed before the if statement and see their values

Comment: Oh... i feel really dumb now... I forgot to set searchPressed = false after its conditions werent needed anymore...  @Lumis post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Nope I just fixed it by setting serachPressed = true somewhere after it was pressed.  I just forgot to do it... :/

Comment: I wasn't the first to notice this, give the points to others :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the two conditions in your first part of the code will fail after the first time.

So either condition

```
search.isPressed()
```

or condition

```
searchPressed == false
```

is not true

Answer (score 1):

My guess from what you've posted so far is that you are actually having trouble because of the if statement, not the startActivity().

Try putting a log output inside this if statement:

```
if (search.isPressed() && searchPressed == false) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Search has been pressed");
        // show search list
        switch1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
        // startActivityForResult(switch1, 0);
        startActivity(switch1);
 }
```

If you don't see your out put in the log cat then the problem is with the if statement. If you post some more of the code from around this if I can try to help figure it out for you. But it seems like your condition is contradicting. To me it looks like you are checking to see if search is both pressed and not pressed.

Post a bit more of the MainActivity code, especially where the searchPressed boolean gets set.